# Help removing wallpaper and painting on old plaster walls

Tags: bathroom, painting, plaster, wallpaper

I think I'm a bit over my head with this. This is my first major do it alone DIY. My fiance and I just bought a co-op built in 1917 and wanted to strip the old vinyl wallpaper from the bathroom.

I'm hoping to remove all the wallpaper and on one wall apply a new coat of wallpaper, and then on the other walls paint it white. I’m worried I’m damaging the walls while stripping.

It seems like the top layer of plaster is chipping and being pulled off in places from the base layer. How should I best remove the wallpaper? And am I causing serious damage to my walls by doing this or by accidentally removing the top layer of plaster?

Do I even need this top layer of plaster? Or would it be best to chip it away and then apply kilz, then primer, then paint? (Can I apply wallpaper on top of all that too?)

Also, a section of wall where a cabinet was previously hanging has a fairly large crack. How should I best fix this?

Sorry for the multitude of questions, and many thanks!

Where the layer of plaster (?) peeled off the wall. 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dyxyu.jpg)

A section of wall next to the part pictured above that seems more like Sheetrock. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FUPN.jpg)

And a section of wall that wasn’t covered in wallpaper but hidden behind a cabinet. It’s cracked and has some water staining.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruGud.jpg)

Comment: I would patch, add wallpaper and paint it with multi shades of pastel using sea sponge above oak chair rail and solid colour below

Comment: Plaster will crack too easily with paint and cellulose wallpaper with paint will be stronger. If deep long cracks then V-score , repair with flat fibreglass , wallpaper then paint